# How can I clean up XML contact files from Windows?

Tags: contacts

I copied my Windows Vista "contacts" file into Ubuntu and, to my surprise, I can actually read them in Firefox but they're mixed with a lot of extraneous code so they're messy to read and use.

Is there a way in Ubuntu 12.04 to format these xml files so they come out cleaner. Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: You probably need to show us an example..

Comment: open them in gedit and delete what is unwanted?

Comment: You could use a short python script to loop over them, copying only the elements you do want to a new document. An example piece of XML specifying which bits you want to keep would help with giving a full and proper answer.